# Varying font sizes when using different .ttf fonts with no change to the sp

Tags: android, fonts, custom-font

**Problem:** When implementing a custom font I notice quite a big change in the font size. (Without any altering to the font size in the XML file)

This is causing a significant variation between the Actual font size in comparison to the size shown in the Graphical layout in ADT. (Visually about 20sp smaller)

I am building a timer application and want to use a Digital Looking font.

**Question:** Can a .ttf file affect the font size relative to a constant 'sp' ?

Comment: OK so I have determined that yes. the .ttf can affect the font size relative to a consistent font 'sp'.

Basically just did a bit of trial and error with various .ttf files.

Comment: I would be interested to know how I could "Scale" a specific font rather than just increase the 'sp' in the XML file however.

Comment: OK so i figured out how to change the base size of a .ttf using FontForge (http://fontforge.org/) There is a great tutorial on how to do this here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=990853 I did have to play around with more options then noted in the tutorial to get my font just right but it works perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question.

YES. a .ttf file does have a 'base font size' and this may vary from one .ttf to another.

As stated in my comment above:

I figured out how to change the base size of a .ttf using FontForge (fontforge.org) There is a great tutorial on how to do this here: [forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=990853](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=990853) I did have to play around with more options then noted in the tutorial to get my font just right but it works perfect!